# Can I insert a Component TEMPLATE Link in the Tridion GUI?

Tags: templates, schema, tridion

In Tridion, similar to how a field in a schema or metadata schema can either be text, embedded schema, or component link... is there a way to allow the field to be an item select like a component link, but select different types of Tridion objects instead of components?

I'd like the user to be able to select a Compound Component Template or a Page object via selecting it through the interface instead of typing in the tcm into a text field and reading that value.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. Links to Component Templates are not handled by the Tridion GUIs. The Tridion Content Manager back-end can handle links to Component Templates in some situations, which is why (for example) you can see the Component Templates show up in the WhereUsed dialog of a Page.

Most people end up using a regular text field for holding such a Component Template link and then use something like [Bart's Item Selector](http://www.sdltridionworld.com/community/2011_extensions/itemselector.aspx) to provide an input aid.

Comment: Thanks! I'll have to review the Bart's Item Selector with the db/software install guys, but that looks like it might solve it.

Answer (score 4):

You must be careful by creating links to other types than components because they might not be content portable and you will get issues after porting those fields from one environment to another.

Basically the tcm uris won't be resolved by content porter.

Answer (score 3):

This would have to be achieved by building a custom CME (GUI) extension.